# How to remove slug from Product category URL in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How to remove product category  slug like "product-category" from URL any 
hook suggestion code, any plugin or any custom code

Answer (score 1):

As the WooCommerce Development Team suggest that you [don’t remove the product_category](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/removing-product-product-category-or-shop-from-the-urls/) base slug completely. Because it stops WordPress from being able to distinguish whether it is a page or product category.

Although you can change the Product Category Base Slug:

1. Go to Settings -> Permalinks -> Optional -> Product category base
2. Instead of product-category you can write cat
3. Click on Save Changes

Comment: Nops i know that one I want completely remove slug from url  @cryptex_vinci